# SQL JOIN having a result of table rows to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I'm trying to connect two tables and show the matching rows as columns.
ps_product table contains the values of the product, ps_image_shop contains the image values and id's linking to the product. What I would like to have is, showing matching rows as column at SQL result below.

**Table 1** (ps_product) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMZxd.png)

**Table 2** (ps_image_shop) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I93tJ.png)

**CURRENT SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.`id_product`  AS `id_product`,
 p.`reference`  AS `reference`,
 sa.`price`  AS `price`,
 p.`id_shop_default`  AS `id_shop_default`,
 p.`is_virtual`  AS `is_virtual`,
 pl.`name`  AS `name`,
 pl.`link_rewrite`  AS `link_rewrite`,
 sa.`active`  AS `active`,
 shop.`name`  AS `shopname`,
 image_shop.`id_image`  AS `id_image`,
 cl.`name`  AS `name_category`,
 0 AS `price_final`,
 pd.`nb_downloadable`  AS `nb_downloadable`,
 sav.`quantity`  AS `sav_quantity`,
 IF(sav.`quantity`<=0, 1, 0) AS `badge_danger` 
FROM  `ps_product` p 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (pl.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = 1 AND pl.`id_shop` = 1) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_stock_available` sav ON (sav.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND sav.`id_product_attribute` = 0 AND sav.id_shop = 1  AND sav.id_shop_group = 0 ) 
 JOIN `ps_product_shop` sa ON (p.`id_product` = sa.`id_product` AND sa.id_shop = 1) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` cl ON (sa.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = 1 AND cl.id_shop = 1) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_category` c ON (c.`id_category` = cl.`id_category`) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_shop` shop ON (shop.id_shop = 1) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_image_shop` image_shop ON (image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.id_shop = 1) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_image` i ON (i.`id_image` = image_shop.`id_image`) 
 LEFT JOIN `ps_product_download` pd ON (pd.`id_product` = p.`id_product`) 
WHERE (1 AND state = 1)
ORDER BY  `id_product` desc
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

CREATE QUERIES

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_product` (
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_supplier` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_manufacturer` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_category_default` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_shop_default` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_tax_rules_group` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `on_sale` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `online_only` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ean13` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ecotax` decimal(17,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `quantity` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=138 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_image_shop` (
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_image` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_shop` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cover` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please provide your source table structures as editable text (i.e. as CREATE statements), not pictures. Also provide some sample source data and the expected result - as text, not pictures

Comment: Hello @NickW, basically I want to join two tables that has some unique id. List the second table as columns, instead of rows. Create queries are at revised question.

Comment: Complex queries are difficult to work with.  It is easier to break the problem into pieces inside a transaction block, and use temp tables for intermediate results.

Comment: I have executed your query on a PS 1.7 database a it works properly. Detail  your expected results.